# A button that sends information to the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I got an internship assignment with javascript, and since I've only been learning for a week, I'm not very good at writing code.
I need to make a button that will send information about timestamp, logged in user and the number of the clicked button to webservice, and on this basis also put the data in the database (I'm using mongodb). Can someone show me the way? I did server in node, mongo-schema and api-routes. But it doesn't work. Also, I don't know how to assign this action to the button

Comment: Unfortunately we can't develop your application for you. Stackoverflow is for people who have a specific problem, tried to write some code but need help solving their particular problem. Your question is basically "How do I write an application and do things?" and your particular problem is "it doesn't work" which is... well... a _little_ too vague maybe? :) I'm afraid the only way is to watch tutorials and experiment on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Well this might not be appropriate to ask here, but since you are new lemme help u this time.

The following might be the route to success here:

1. Develop a rest endpoint (a POST request) in node - express that accepts the request.
2. Write a javascript function that sends the request to the api using ajax.

Follow a lot of tutorials like the comments say to get an understanding.
The below links might be useful
https://medium.com/@onejohi/building-a-simple-rest-api-with-nodejs-and-express-da6273ed7ca9
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/here-is-the-most-popular-ways-to-make-an-http-request-in-javascript-954ce8c95aaa/